# ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

i am new to Angular 4 and trying to build a simple routing but when i am trying to redirect on successful register using `this.router.navigate(['./admin/login']);` so its throwing this error `ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges` in `console.log`. Here is how my `register.component.ts` file looks like:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

import { FormValidationService } from "../../validations/form-validation.service";
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'register.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnDestroy  {
  name: String;
  email: String;
  password: String;
  re_password: String;
  mobile:String;


  constructor(private formValidation: FormValidationService, 
            private flash: FlashMessagesService, 
            private auth: AuthService,
            private router: Router) { }




  registerUser(){   
    var user = {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        re_password: this.re_password,
        mobile:this.mobile,
    }



    if(!this.formValidation.validateEmail(this.email)){
        this.flash.show("Invalid email format!",{ cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
        return false;
    }

    this.auth.authRegisterUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success){
        this.flash.show("User created successfully!", { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
        this.router.navigate(['./admin/login']);     // <-------This is the problem -------------->
      }else{
        this.flash.show(data.message, { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
        return false;
      }
    });

  }

}
```

And i have created a `auth.module.ts` file in which i have mentioned the route for these two.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register.component';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';


import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ AuthRoutingModule, FormsModule, FlashMessagesModule ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Also i have this routing file `auth-routing.module.ts` here you can view the file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Example Pages'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Login Page'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Register Page'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

Now where is the problem not getting it. Its showing this Console here is the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Any suggestion will be helpful. 
Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: Unsubscribe your events in ngOnDestroy function by implementing OnDestroy interface.

Comment: @omeralper what kind of event you are talking about here? Click event you mean?

Comment: @Vega we have one more route in which we have imported this route.

Comment: @user3201500 you have only one event in RegisterComponent this.auth.authRegisterUser, I suppose it causes this error.

Comment: @omeralper how can i disable it? Or any alternative solution for the same?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually not the rerouting, but with flash-messages. In your RegisterComponent's html, you have the `<flash-messages></flash-messages>`;  after the user is registered, you 1. call flash-messages, 2. reroute to login page.

```
this.flash.show("User created successfully!", { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
this.router.navigate(['./admin/login']);
```

The problem is that flash-messages is being told to display in the RegisterComponent.html file, which is destroyed by the reroute, so that results in flash-messages trying to display its message in the destroyed 'Register' view.

I currently don't know of any way around this.  It appears that an app can only have flash-messages in one permanent location.  One solution you could use is to put your flash-messages selector somewhere in app.component.  Another solution would be to emit a notification from RegisterComponent that gets picked up by the view component you wish to display a message in, and sort of 'mock' a flash-message with a div styled like flash-message and a timeout.